# Cron jobs not running

Tags: cron

Can anyone provide insight to why my cron jobs are not running?  I has tried simple jobs, like a date/time job, and it works.

Below is an example of what I am trying to run:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: taxscribe
0 0,6,12,18 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/taxscribe/releases/20110311205859 && RAILS_ENV=production rake informer:sync:submitted --silent'

0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/taxscribe/releases/20110311205859 && RAILS_ENV=production rake informer:sync:extensions --silent'

0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/taxscribe/releases/20110311205859 && RAILS_ENV=production rake informer:sync:accounts --silent'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: taxscribe
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this in the per-user `crontab` or in the system-wide `crontab`? If it's the latter, then it needs a `user` field` before the command.

Comment: it is in the per-user under our deploy user

Comment: Why are you running these in a subshell? They are already going to run in a subshell. This might be part of the problem. Remove the `/bin/bash -l -c '` and the matching end quote, and add `SHELL=/bin/bash' to the top of the crontab.

Answer (score 3):

maybe `rake` isn't in the PATH when crond attempts to execute the job? (try putting the full path to the rake binary)

Comment: when I run each job manually they run fine.

Comment: yep but when run from crond, the PATH might be different. Simply replace "rake" with "/full/path/to/rake" and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks ggiroux...it looks like putting the full path in the job makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that crond is running

```
pgrep crond
```

Comment: crond is running b/c it provides me with the pid number

Comment: The cron daemon is not called `crond` on all systems. On my gentoo box it's just `cron`. `pgrep cron` would match both variants.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if crond is running and also check to see that it is set to startup with the system

`chkconfig crond --list`

if it isn't then do

`chkconfig crond on`

to have have it start at boot.

Also check your logs. Ensure that there isn't an error in your scripts preventing execution.

`/var/log/cron`

Comment: I dont have a cron log

Answer (score 0):

If the jobs that you are running produce any output then cron will have mailed that to the account that was running the job.

You could capture the output of the jobs to a log file e.g.

`/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/taxscribe/releases/20110311205859 && RAILS_ENV=production rake informer:sync:submitted --silent &>/path/to/file.log'`

and see what it has to say.

Comment: when i try to add the log file to the end of the job, i get permission denied when run them manually...I assume it has to do with being signed in as a deploy user

Comment: @Queencity13: change the /path/to/file.log to something that you can write to.